# How to Trim and Explode Variable?

Tags: php

I want to separate these string

```php
$x = "/user12345 lorem ipsum dolor"; //the 12345 is unique number
```

into two parts **`12345`** and **`lorem ipsum dolor`** and then remove the **`/user`**. so the result is should be

```php
$x1 = "12345";
$x2 = "lorem ipsum dolor";
```

ive tried these code but isnt working well

```php
$x = "/user12345 lorem ipsum dolor";
$z = explode("/user", trim($x));
$result = trim($z[1]);

echo $result;
//the output is: 12345 lorem ipsum dolor
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have nominated two delimiters and only want two elements in your output array.

The following pattern splits on the `/user` substring at the start of the string or on a space.  The third parameter of `preg_split()` limits the output to two elements, the fourth parameter excludes any empty elements -- like the zero-length one created before `/user`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9BJuF))

```
$x = "/user12345 lorem ipsum dolor";

var_export(
    preg_split('~^/user| ~', $x, 2, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '12345',
  1 => 'lorem ipsum dolor',
)
```

---

If you'd rather make two function calls instead of regex, left-trim the characters before the user number, then explode with a limit of 2.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NkJcF))

```
var_export(
    explode(
        ' ', 
        ltrim($x, 'ersu/'),
        2
    )
);
// same output as previous snippet
```

---

For comparison, unless you need "validation" with your "extraction", `preg_match()` returns 3 elements while you need only two.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Y2moM))

```
if (!preg_match('~^/user(\d+) (.+)~', $x, $match)) {
    echo 'no match';
} else {
    [, $x1, $x2] = $match;
    var_export($x1);
    echo "\n";
    var_export($x2);
}
```

There is no need to include the end-of-string anchor (`$`) because the greedy `+` will match to the end.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of possibilities, one using [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`substr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and the other using [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match):

```
$x = "/user12345 lorem ipsum dolor";

$z = explode(' ', $x, 2);
$z[0] = substr($z[0], 5);
print_r($z);

preg_match('#^/user(\d+)\s+(.*)$#', $x, $z);
array_shift($z);
print_r($z);
```

In both cases the output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12345
    [1] => lorem ipsum dolor
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/kshdN)

Answer (score 1):

```
$userinfo = "/user12345 lorem ipsum dolor";
preg_match("/\/user(\d+) ([A-z ]+)/", $userinfo, $pat_array);

$x1 = $pat_array[1];
$x2 = $pat_array[2];
```

Comment: `preg_match_all()` is unnecessary since there is only one line to match.  There is also no reason to capture the word `user` - this is unnecessary output array bloat.

Comment: Still needless capture group and unorthodox character class instead of case insensitive flag.  All answer MUST include an exolanation to be useful.